# auth:user show blank in moduls controller laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-authentication

I'm working on custom modules in laravel and getting unable to access

```
print_r(Auth::user());
```

it show me blank.

my route is inside modules

```
Route::group(['module' => 'ScreenColors', 'middleware' => ['web'], 
   'namespace' => 'App\Modules\ScreenColors\Controllers'], 
    function() {
      Route::get('/screen_colors', 'ScreenColorsController@index');
    }
);
```

My modules directory is `app\Modules\ScreenColors`
using ArtemSchander modules  packages

How can I access auth details into modules controller? Thanks.

Comment: Have you edited your middleware or default middleware group? you must be sure that your route is encapsulated in the correct middleware to manage Auth: session for example.

Comment: no i have not edited my middleware can you let me know which kind of modification needed to get auth in modules controller?

Comment: where are you trying to call `Auth::user()` ... what file, the method?

Comment: Could you post your 'web' group middleware list? In /app/http/Kernel.php.

Comment: 'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

Comment: @lagbox I am trying to call Auth::user() in ScreenColorsController inside modules controller file.
 'namespace' => 'App\Modules\ScreenColors\Controllers'

Comment: have you tried to call it like this \Auth::user()